# How to read a text file from spring xd module jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-xd

I have a spring xd module, which is packaged as jar file. I want to put a text file in resources and read data from that file when the module is launched.

What I have tried so far is

```
   Thread.currentThread().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file")
   Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("file")
```

But it didn't work.
How do I read text files from module jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.

You just add a member to you Tasklet class

```
@Autowire
ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
```

And when you need to load a file from jar you just do this.

```
InputStream stream = resourceLoader.getResource("/path/inside/jar/file").getInputStream();
```

Dont' forget to close the stream :)